# Powering a Behringer MicroMIX MX400 - Car Audio Application

Tags: power-supply, power, audio, automotive

I am installing a car audio system that will have TWO aux inputs; one in the dash and one in the rear passanger seat are.

I decided to purchase the Behringer MicroMIX MX400 mixer. The power spec for the mixer is: 12v DC/150mA. It comes with a power supply that plugs into a wall outlet. I need to power it in a vehicle. Since it’s already 12V DC, I was thinking just connecting it to an unused/open circuit the interior fuse box that is 5A switched (only active when key is in the ignition). The power will be connected to the fuse box circuit and I’ll just ground it to an exiting ground point.

Will that work?

Answer (score 1):

You should check the voltage ratings of the mixer itself - it may not be happy with the 14 or 15 volts that a car will actually be using when the engine is running. Fitting a DC to Dc converter to create a stable power supply would be a better idea.

Comment: This should probably be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Hearth I don't care about the input V specs... I just pointed out the safer way for the OP to achieve powering the device... especially as **some** don't realize the difference between battery voltage and running voltage on cars...

Comment: Ah, yes! Good point Solar Mike! The specs say exactly 12v DC. I had overlooked that the running voltage varies, especially with an amo and subwoofer running. What do you suggest to get a constant 12v?

Comment: @Inked_xx a dc to dc converter as mentioned in the answer....

Comment: UPDATE: So today I tested the power supply (100-240v AC to 12v DC) by plugging it in to the wall outlet and testing the plug with a multimeter. I got a reading of 11.83v. Will this change anything as far as what kind of power supply I can use? I’ve been doing non-stop research and cannot find a simple solution to this. I don’t have any experience using buck-boost DC-DC regulators/converter.

Comment: Would this work HeavenLights DC 5v to DC 12v Converter Step Up Voltage Converter DC - DC from 5V to 12V USB to 5.5 x 2.1mm https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0796RNK4V/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_i_HrNbCb2C5GBZV

Comment: Perhaps something like: https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/DC-4V-38V-to-1-25V-36V-2A-Step-Down-Power-Supply-Regulator-24V-12V-9V-5V-UK/122572089413?epid=806469670&hash=item1c89dda845:g:GqEAAOSwVpVbIBvw